# can a program read its own elf section?

Tags: linux, elf, backtrace

I would like to use ld's --build-id option in order to add build information to my binary. However, I'm not sure how to make this information available inside the program. Assume I want to write a program that writes a backtrace every time an exception occurs, and a script that parses this information. The script reads the symbol table of the program and searches for the addresses printed in the backtrace (I'm forced to use such a script because the program is statically linked and backtrace_symbols is not working). In order for the script to work correctly I need to match build version of the program with the build version of the program which created the backtrace. How can I print the build version of the program (located in the .note.gnu.build-id elf section) from the program itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I print the build version of the program (located in the .note.gnu.build-id elf section) from the program itself?

1. You need to read the `ElfW(Ehdr)` (at the beginning of the file) to find program headers in your binary (`.e_phoff` and `.e_phnum` will tell you where program headers are, and how many of them to read).
2. You then read program headers, until you find  `PT_NOTE` segment of your program. That segment will tell you offset to the beginning of all the notes in your binary.
3. You then need to read the `ElfW(Nhdr)` and skip the rest of the note (total size of the note is `sizeof(Nhdr) + .n_namesz + .n_descsz`, properly aligned), until you find a note with  `.n_type == NT_GNU_BUILD_ID`.
4. Once you find `NT_GNU_BUILD_ID` note, skip past its `.n_namesz`, and read the `.n_descsz` bytes to read the actual build-id.

You can verify that you are reading the right data by comparing what you read with the output of `readelf -n a.out`.

P.S.

If you are going to go through the trouble to decode build-id as above, and *if* your executable is not stripped, it may be better for you to just decode and print *symbol* names instead (i.e. to replicate what `backtrace_symbols` does) -- it's actually easier to do than decoding ELF notes, because the symbol table contains fixed-sized entries.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a program can read its own `.note.gnu.build-id`. The important piece is the `dl_iterate_phdr` function.

I've used this technique in Mesa (the OpenGL/Vulkan implementation) to read its own build-id for use with the on-disk shader cache.

I've extracted those bits into a separate project[1] for easy use by others.

[1] https://github.com/mattst88/build-id

Answer (score 3):

Basically, this is the code I've written based on answer given to my question. In order to compile the code I had to make some changes and I hope it will work for as many types of platforms as possible. However, it was tested only on one build machine. One of the assumptions I used was that the program was built on the machine which runs it so no point in checking endianness compatibility between the program and the machine.

```
user@:~/$ uname -s -r -m -o
Linux 3.2.0-45-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
user@:~/$ g++ test.cpp -o test
user@:~/$ readelf -n test | grep Build
    Build ID: dc5c4682e0282e2bd8bc2d3b61cfe35826aa34fc
user@:~/$ ./test
    Build ID: dc5c4682e0282e2bd8bc2d3b61cfe35826aa34fc
```

```c
#include <elf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#if __x86_64__
#  define ElfW(type) Elf64_##type
#else
#  define ElfW(type) Elf32_##type
#endif

/*
detecting build id of a program from its note section
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637745/can-a-program-read-its-own-elf-section
http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/pkg/uclibc/utils/readelf.c
http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2000-07-17/ch5.pheader.html#note_section
*/

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char *thefilename = argv[0];
  FILE *thefile;
  struct stat statbuf;
  ElfW(Ehdr) *ehdr = 0;
  ElfW(Phdr) *phdr = 0;
  ElfW(Nhdr) *nhdr = 0;
  if (!(thefile = fopen(thefilename, "r"))) {
    perror(thefilename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (fstat(fileno(thefile), &statbuf) < 0) {
    perror(thefilename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ehdr = (ElfW(Ehdr) *)mmap(0, statbuf.st_size, 
    PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fileno(thefile), 0);
  phdr = (ElfW(Phdr) *)(ehdr->e_phoff + (size_t)ehdr);
  while (phdr->p_type != PT_NOTE)
  {
    ++phdr;
  }
  nhdr = (ElfW(Nhdr) *)(phdr->p_offset + (size_t)ehdr); 
  while (nhdr->n_type != NT_GNU_BUILD_ID)
  {
    nhdr = (ElfW(Nhdr) *)((size_t)nhdr + sizeof(ElfW(Nhdr)) + nhdr->n_namesz + nhdr->n_descsz);
  }
  unsigned char * build_id = (unsigned char *)malloc(nhdr->n_descsz);
  memcpy(build_id, (void *)((size_t)nhdr + sizeof(ElfW(Nhdr)) + nhdr->n_namesz), nhdr->n_descsz);
  printf("    Build ID: ");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < nhdr->n_descsz ; ++i)
  {
    printf("%02x",build_id[i]);
  }
  free(build_id);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote my own code for this ...

```
#include <fcntl.h>      // open
#include <unistd.h>     // close
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <string.h>     // strncmp
#include <libelf.h>     // elf_*
#include <gelf.h>       // gelf_*

// Compile as: gcc -o read_build_id read_build_id.c -lelf

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: %s <elf-file>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Determine the working version (the ELF version supported by both, the libelf library and this program).
  if (elf_version(EV_CURRENT) == EV_NONE)
  {
    printf("Warning: libelf is out of date. Can't read build-id of \"%s\" (or any object file).\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  // Open the ELF object file.
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

  // Open an ELF descriptor for reading.
  Elf* e = elf_begin(fd, ELF_C_READ, NULL);

  if (!e)
  {
    printf("Warning: elf_begin returned NULL for \"%s\": %s\n", argv[1], elf_errmsg(-1));
    return 1;
  }

  if (elf_kind(e) != ELF_K_ELF)
  {
    printf("%s: skipping, not an ELF file.\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
  }

#if 0
  // Get the string table section index.
  size_t shstrndx;
  if (elf_getshdrstrndx(e, &shstrndx) != 0)
  {
    printf("elf_getshdrstrndx() failed: %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));
    return 1;
  }
#endif

  // Run over all sections in the ELF file.
  Elf_Scn* scn = NULL;
  while ((scn = elf_nextscn(e, scn)) != NULL)
  {
    // Get the section header.
    GElf_Shdr shdr;
    gelf_getshdr(scn, &shdr);

    if (shdr.sh_type == SHT_NOTE)
    {
#if 0
      // Get the name of the section
      char const* name = elf_strptr(e, shstrndx, shdr.sh_name);
      printf("Section: %s\n", name);
#endif

      Elf_Data* data = elf_getdata(scn, NULL);
      GElf_Nhdr nhdr;
      size_t name_offset, desc_offset;

      size_t offset = 0;
      while ((offset = gelf_getnote(data, offset, &nhdr, &name_offset, &desc_offset)) > 0)
      {
        if (nhdr.n_type == NT_GNU_BUILD_ID && nhdr.n_namesz == 4 && strncmp((char*)data->d_buf + name_offset, "GNU", 4) == 0)
        {
          printf("Found build ID: ");
          unsigned char *desc = (unsigned char *)data->d_buf + desc_offset;
          for (int i = 0; i < nhdr.n_descsz; ++i)
            printf("%02x", desc[i]);
          printf("\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  elf_end(e);
  close(fd);
}
```