# Is there a way to embed a string in C++ source code that will show up in a core dump?

Tags: c++, gdb

With lots of versions of binaries, if I receive a core dump, I currently rely on the sender telling me the version they were running so I can match it with the right source/symbols that built it.  They are often incorrect and much time is wasted.  Even asking them to send the binary with the core is error-prone.  Is there a way to embed a version string into the source code that I can look for in a core dump?  Or is there some kind of hash/signature I can use to match it from a build?  Or is there a better convention?

Comment: Not sure if it's feasible for you, but I have my software, when generating a dmp file, name the file `Product_vMajor.Minor.Build.dmp` or something to that effect. That way the build version is directly in the file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I currently rely on the sender telling me the version they were running so I can match it with the right source/symbols that built it.

Since you are talking about `core` dumps, it seems exceedingly likely that you are using an ELF platform (probably Linux).

On an ELF platform, *the* standard way to identify a binary is to use `--build-id` linker flag, which embeds a unique checksum into the binary. This is likely passed to the linker from `g++` by default, but you can explicitly specify that flag with `-Wl,--build-id` as well.

Linux kernel saves the page containing the `NT_GNU_BUILD_ID` ELF note, which allows you to

1. Immediately identify what binary produced the core (using e.g. `eu-unstrip -n --core core`) and
2. Use GDB to *automatically* load correct debug info. See e.g [this article](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=73a2a5bd-b224-4bff-9267-3eea4cf5f00e#gsc.tab=0).

Comment: Even though I was looking for the ability to do something more like having "release-1.2.3" in the core, this is clearly the "right" way.  Additionally, I can access the build-id at runtime via this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55641889/access-build-id-at-runtime.  And finally I still get what I want by using alloca on my main thread's stack an copying the version string there - I'm able to see that in the core as well, so best of all worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Can your `main` call a generated `int build6278()` function which then call into you real entry point? Your build system would need to generate this stub with a different name per version.

Then you just need to look up the callstack and find this function name. This assumes a build with symbols.

Alternatively, using your suggestion:

```
int main()
{
    const char* version = g_Version; // that symbol will have to be added by your build system
    std::cout << g_Version << std::endl;
    return regularMain();
}
```

should allow you to check the local `version` pointer in the crash dump.

Comment: It could, and I do build with symbols, but I strip them out before release so presumably I'd still be in the same boat.  Although it got me thinking; I could allocate a string on the heap with the version... or put it on the stack of the main thread...

Comment: Just do something to convince the compiler to not optimize it out.

Comment: Would it work to use an integer instead of a string and pass it as an argument to `regularMain()`?

Comment: Yes that's another good thought... an integer has the advantage of not being a reference with data residing elsewhere.  I'll play with it...